# How to test a remote port is reachable with socat

Tags: linux, socat

How to test a remote port is reachable with socat?

with netcat we can

```
nc -zv 192.168.1.15 22
```

How to do that with socat?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the OP requested the equivalent of `-z` the following `socat` command will ensure that it does not wait for input and just checks if the port is listening or not.

```
socat /dev/null TCP:remote:port
```

This can be used in a Docker context especially on health checks for the `alpine/socat` image.  Here is an example that sets up a forwarder for the `smtp` service to a `mailhog` service and checks if the connection is up

```
services:
  smtp:
    image: alpine/socat
    command: tcp-listen:25,fork TCP:mailhog:1025
    healthcheck: socat /dev/null TCP:mailhog:1025
```

Comment: This is a good answer for a scripted solution in which one needs to test whether or not there is an Internet connection: `socat /dev/null TCP:google.com:443`, and then test `$?` for `0` - success or `1` - failure.

Answer (score 4):

I would imagine that the first example in the man page would work

```
socat - TCP4:www.domain.org:80
```

For your example, this would be (and adding 2 second connect timeout):

```
socat - TCP4:192.168.1.15:22,connect-timeout=2
```

and the response would be the sshd connect banner (if that is what is listening)

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

or

```
socat[12650] E connecting to AF=2 192.168.189.6:23: Connection timed out
```

Comment: This is not correct. What is the `-` doing in the command? Answer: Not a damn thing! Except to delay a response. How did 5 people upvote this??

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brief test I use in my `bash` scripts (probably works in `zsh` also):

```bash
while :
do
    socat /dev/null TCP4:google.com:443 && break
    sleep 60
done
```

`socat` is placed inside an infinite loop; when it succeeds (i.e. the Internet is connected to my LAN) the `break` is executed which exits the loop. If it fails, it sleeps for 1 minute (`sleep 60`), and `socat` tests the connection again. I've found this effective in avoiding script failures due to short-term Internet outages.